Unlisted plane crash site in wilderness
I found what is probably a very old plane crash site but I am unable to find any info on it. When I search on maps of plane crash sites in the area, it would appear to be unlisted. How do I find further info on this before bothering anyone with something reported long ago. I got in about a half mile or so but it's in some very thick wilderness so I haven't completed the hike yet, but plan to soon. Maps seem to show 'wear' on the terrain around the area which is why I think this is an old crash site. It's location is 46°26'53.8"N 122°04'27.0"W. Any thoughts on the matter appreciated.

Why do you think there is a plane crash site there, if it is not listed and you have not been there?

I'm pretty sure that a crash of a plane of that size wouldn't pass unnoticed.

Intrerestingly the "plane" seems quite recent, it is not present in Bing Maps.

If it was real, it couldn’t be older than May 1980.

@300D7309EF17, it looks outside the blast zone to me.

I'm sorry but "I found" must have a different meaning for me. I was really confused about the answer to this question until I realized you were just browsing pictures online.

The image is from Google Maps, and that is where I "found it" as I was hiking in that area. Sorry that wasn't obvious enough. Thank you for your input.

That picture confused me, but it is simply a plane flying over that region when the satellite took a picture. You can see that is slightly blurred because it was in motion:

It is in the middle of different airways, not sure which one due to perspective (the LL circle is the position of the aircraft):

P.S. Good catch!

Of course! In motion. I feel silly haha. Well what fooled me is the trail cut in that parallels the forest road. All of this area including the forest road is jungle thick. If you pan out on maps you can see it looks like the parallel trail could've been cut for the purpose of getting to the plane had it actually been there. Lol! Thanks for taking the time to answer and saving me a good days hike to find nothing!

The Google Earth image in 3D mode was really confusing me, because the aicraft appears to follow the mountain slope...

The spaced colored images are typical of a moving airplane photographed by a satellite.  Here's a clearer example, with the airplane's deceleration matched by closer spacing.

Pretty sure an actual crashed plane of this size would not be nearly this intact.

For some reason this all makes me think of Mater's Ghost Lights ...
